# move_uploaded_file não consegue pegar um arquivo

Tags: php, html, arquivo

Olá, o `move_uploaded_file` não consegue pegar um arquivo.

```
        echo "  <form  method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"testar_formato.php\" id=\"upload-container\" class=\"fileUpload\">
                <span>Upload</span>
                <input id=\"arquivo\" class=\"upload\" type=\"file\" />
                <br>
                <input id=\"enviar\" type=\"submit\" />
            </form>";
```

Esse arquivo aqui:

```
        echo "  <form action=\"testar_formato.php\" id=\"upload-container\" class=\"fileUpload\">
                <span>Upload</span>
                <input id=\"arquivo\" class=\"upload\" type=\"file\" />
                <br>
                <input id=\"enviar\" type=\"submit\" />
            </form>";
```

Dá esse erro:

[image]

E essa é a linha 2:

```
$arquivo_up = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
```

Comment: Está faltando `name="arquivo"` no seu `<input>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o atributo `name` ao seu `input`:

`<input id=\"arquivo\" name=\"arquivo\" class=\"upload\" type=\"file\" />`